# How to get annotation's parameters from a class in jar file

Tags: java, jar, annotations

I want to get a class's (packaged in jar file) annotation parameters by java reflect.

1. My annotation like this

   ```
   @Documented
   @Retention(RUNTIME)
   @Target(TYPE)    
   public @interface TestPlugin {
       public String moduleName();
       public String plugVersion();
       public String minLeapVersion();    
   }
   ```
2. My class like this

   ```
   @TestPlugin(moduleName="xxx", plugVersion="1.0.0", minLeapVersion="1.3.0")

   public class Plugin {

     ......

   }
   ```
3. My access code like this

   ```
   Class<?> clazz = this.loadClass(mainClassName);  // myself classloader

   Annotation[] annos = clazz.getAnnotations();

   for (Annotation anno : annos) {
       Class<? extends Annotation> annoClass = anno.annotationType();

       /* Question is here
       This code can get right annotationType: @TestPlugin. 
       Debug windows show anno is $Proxy33. 
       But I can't find any method to get annotation membervalues even though I can find them in debug windows.
       How can I get annotation's parameters?
       */
   }
   ```

   [Debug windows info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaPoM.png)

Comment: Debug windows can be found in attached picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "real" annotation classes used by the Java VM are Dynamic Proxies for some technical reasons. This shouldn't bother you. They still "implement" your annotation class. Just use

```
TestPlugin plugin = clazz.getAnnotation(TestPlugin.class);

plugin.getClass() == TestPlugin.class; // false - is Dynamic proxy
TestPlugin.class.isAssignableFrom(plugin.getClass()); // true - Dynamic proxy implements TestPlugin interface
```

EDIT: Just found in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20362771/2235015), that you could also ask your `anno` object in your loop, but do not use `getClass()`. Use `.annotationType()`.