# Retrieve annotation by name

Tags: java, reflection, java-8, annotations

I know it's possible to get a class by name, using

```
public String className = "someName";
public Class<?> c = Class.forName(className);
```

Is it possible to retrieve an annotation by name? I tried this:

```
public String annotationName = "someName";
public Class<?> c = Class.forName(annotationName);
```

And then casting c to `Class<? extends Annotation>`, which works, but I get an Unchecked cast warning.

I also tried

```
public String annotationName = "someName";
public Class<? extends Annotation> c = Class.forName(annotationName);
```

But when I do that I get the error

```
Incompatible types.
Required: Class<? extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation>
Found: Class<Capture<?>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get annotation class name, attribute values using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362493/how-to-get-annotation-class-name-attribute-values-using-reflection)

Comment: @HadiJ If I understand correctly, that question deals with trying to retrieve all annotation names. My question is if I already have a specific annotation name, how to get to the annotation

Comment: The first way you showed is the way to do it. You can't do anything to the unchecked cast warning except to suppress it. That's just a limitation in Java's generics.

Comment: *And then casting c to Class<? extends Annotation>, which works* - can't be possible, bounded types only work if they involve an interface or class

Comment: @Eugene [`Annotation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html) *is* an interface.

Comment: @Sweeper Not correct. [There is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56107929/2711488) a type safe solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`asSubclass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass-java.lang.Class-). Unlike compiler generated type casts, which can only work with types known at compile-time, this will perform a check against the `Class` object retrieved at runtime. Since this is safe, it won’t generated an “Unchecked cast” warning. Note the existence of a similar operation, [`cast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-) for casting an instance of a `Class`. These methods were added in Java 5, specifically to aid code using Generics.

```
String annotationName = "java.lang.Deprecated";
Class<? extends Annotation> c = Class.forName(annotationName).asSubclass(Annotation.class);
boolean depr = Thread.class.getMethod("stop").isAnnotationPresent(c);
System.out.println(depr);
```