# Get the annotation variable and its type of a data class

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, data-class, kotlin-reflect

I have a data class in kotlin , which is also a Room entity.
Eg :

```
data class Pack(

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    @SerializedName("name")
    var name:String,

    @SerializedName("is_free")
    @ColumnInfo(name="is_free")
    var isFree:Boolean,

    @SerializedName("is_new")
    @ColumnInfo(name="is_new")
    var isNew:Boolean,

){ .. }
```

I want to get all the values of @ColumnInfo(name) , ie I want all the Room anotation names and its corresponding kotlin varible and its types.
ie I want something like.
Eg :

name - name - String
is_free - isFree - Boolean
is_new - isNew - Boolean

Is that possible using kotlin reflection of something?

Comment: I think this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362493/how-to-get-annotation-class-name-attribute-values-using-reflection

Comment: @Pavel no thats not helping , its outputing some weird values. I guess it is for normal java class . 
Mine is for kotlin data class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can go through the parameters of the primary constructor of your data class, collect the annotations and print them out like this:

```
fun <T: Any> KClass<T>.getInfo(): List<String> = 
    primaryConstructor!!.parameters.map { it.getInfo() }

fun KParameter.getInfo(): String {
    val columnInfo = findAnnotation<ColumnInfo>()
    return "$name - ${columnInfo?.name} - $type"
}
```

Then calling `Pack::class.getInfo()` gives you the following:

```
[name - name - kotlin.String, isFree - is_free - kotlin.Boolean, isNew - is_new - kotlin.Boolean]
```

Comment: It always returns null.