# java.net.URLClassLoader doesn't add class annotations

Tags: java, annotations, classloader, urlclassloader

While developing a ant - task to autogenerate some gui - code for a project using annotations as I prefer a declarative approach I am using the `java.net.URLClassLoader` to dynamically add
the classes to my class path.
When scanning the classes for class - level - annotations none of them is found though
they exists.
e.g.


    `@AutoGenerateGUI

    class LoginBean`

 

Has anyone else experienced this problem and can provide a solution?
(Subclassing the URLClassLoader to make the call to loadClass internally be treated as loadClass(Class clazz, true) didn't work neither)

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103872/marko-topolnik
In Addition:
Retrieving the annotations of the dynamically loaded classes always returned com.sun.proxy.$Proxy[x], so to get to the original annotation type I had to use the construct [URLClassLoader loads Annotation as com.sun.$Proxy$27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282337/urlclassloader-loads-annotation-as-com-sun-proxy27/20730575#20730575) iterating over the interfaces the proxy object implements. Though this should not be necessary, indeed other solutions e.g. using instanceof failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that `AutoGenerateGUI` is your custom annotation, and you haven't specified the correct retention policy for it. The default is `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`, which will discard the annotation after loading the class. The annotation will not be available through reflection at runtime.

Comment: Yes, perfect. I oversaw.